# How to use Array elements in a if-else statement?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

I have two Numpy arrays, say `a` and `b`, each having a single one element only, like:
    a = ['op 1']
    b = ['op 2']

I need to use these two for comparison like

```
"if outputs are op 1 and op 2 then print op 2"
"else if outputs are op 1 and op 3 then print op 3"
"else if outputs are op 1 and op 1 then print op 1"
"else if outputs are op 2 and op 2 then print op 2"
"else if outputs are op 3 and op 3 then print op 3"
```

here "outputs" means the content of array 1 and array 2

How can I do this? I'm totally new to Python and NumPy. I saw the NumPy array equal function, but that doesn't work here, right?

Comment: `each gives single output only` what do you mean?

Comment: sorry//i meant each will have only one element

Comment: Okay, so then what's your question? Could you fix it up? Capitalize your `i`s, fix your grammar. Show some effort.

Comment: how to use those elements in if-else

Comment: You should read about python first: https://docs.python.org/3/

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. `if outputs are`... what outputs?

Comment: In this example you could just always print the second one, now ifs required. `print(array2)`

Comment: here "outputs" means the content of array 1 and array 2